# how to close activity after x minutes?

Tags: java, android

I am looking for simplest way to close opened activity after x minutes. Does android provide countdown class or do I have to made one by my self ?

I've tried this code but its not working

```
Thread isOnDisplayThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Timer mTimer = new Timer();
                mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {    
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG, (isApplicationOnDisplay) ? "Application on display" : "APPLICATION ON BACKGROUND");

                        if (!isApplicationOnDisplay) {
                            notOnDisplayTime++;
                            if (notOnDisplayTime >= 10) {

                                Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
                            }
                        } else {
                            notOnDisplayTime = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);
            }
        });

        isOnDisplayThread.run();
```

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: This question can be improved easily. Please correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r=new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                finish();
              }         
            };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
```

Comment: sure i did i like ur code simple and professional , bless u ;)

Answer (score 4):

Never ever ever ever ever* call the `run()` method of a Java `Thread`. Call its `start()` method, which causes Java to call its `run()` method for you *within the new thread*.

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea:

> Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());

You should call finish() function in UI thread. For example, use runOnUiThread(): [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because you are calling the run method. It will not start the thread.
So you need to call the start method to invoke the thread

```
  isOnDisplayThread.start();
```

Also to finish off the thread you need to call the

```
        finish() ///method of the Activity class
```

If the code is with in the Activity class then just call the finish() method

```
    if (notOnDisplayTime >= 10) {

            finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private final long startTime = 200000;
private final long interval = 1000;
countDownTimer = new MalibuCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    countDownTimer.start();
public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
        public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval){
            super(startTime, interval);
        }
            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
                txttimer.setText("Time's up!");                 
                    //timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime));
            }
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //text.setText("Time remain:" + millisUntilFinished);
                    //timeElapsed = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
                    String format = String.format("%%0%dd",2);  
                    String seconds = String.format(format, millisUntilFinished/1000 % 60);  
                     String minutes = String.format(format, (millisUntilFinished /(1000*60))%60);  
                     String hours = String.format(format, (millisUntilFinished /(1000*60*60))%24);  
                     String time =  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;  
                     txttimer.setText("Time Remaining:" + time);
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeElapsed) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeElapsed)),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeElapsed)));
                    System.out.println(hms);
                    //text.setText("Time remain:" + h+":"+m+":"+s);
                    //timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(timeElapsed));   
                }
        }
```

Comment: @ Siddharth Thanks dude! i will take care in future.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the Timer and Call `finish()`. It will close your activity after certain time.

```
  //Declare the timer
  Timer t = new Timer();
  //Set the schedule function and rate
  t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
     finish(); 
}

 },
  //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Handler.postDelayed` method.